# Perforce get latest change CL#

Tags: version-control, perforce

In my perforce workspace, I run these 3 commands:

```
# 1
p4 changes -m1 ./...
Change 11111111 on 2020/01/01 by abc@def 'Jan 1'

#2
p4 changes -m1
Change 11112222 on 2020/02/01 by abc@def 'Feb 1'

#3
p4 changes -m1 //...
Change 11113333 on 2020/03/01 by abc@def 'Mar 1'
```

All three commands result in 3 different outputs

**How do i interpret the results?**

I wanted to know what is the tip of my local workspace (In analogy to `HEAD` in git)
But this seems to be very convoluted in Perforce

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: If you want to find the "tip" in your *local workspace* (i.e. not the "tip" in the server, which would correspond to a remote in Git) you want to use the `#have` revision specifier as well.  See linked dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if you are interested only with submitted changes (without pending changelists) you could specify -s submitted option to your command line.

Your local workspace may not include whole repo, just some view of it, defined by workspace mapping.

If you want to get global head revision you may use:

```
p4 changes -m 1 -s submitted
```

If you want to get head revision of current directory:

```
p4 changes -m 1 -s submitted ./...
```

More you can find out in `p4 help changes`